# Import gmail certificate in Pidgin

Tags: ssl, pidgin, gmail

There is a bug with Pidgin, where the certificate for gmail.com cannot be validated.

[image]

The problem is discussed [here](https://developer.pidgin.im/ticket/17118) and there is also a solution:

```
openssl s_client -showcerts -servername gmail.com -connect gmail.com:443
```

That outputs the certificate in terminal as it should, like [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/13838/47206), but I don't know how to add that to Pidgin for a gmail account.

At the ticket/bug link it says

> this will retrieve correct certificate with CN=gmail.com
>
> after importing it into pidgin (Tools->Certificates) it should work
>   fine

I have read that it should be saved in a text file in `~/.purple/certificates/x509/tls_peers` that should be called `username@gmail.com`, but that doesn't work.

[image]

Comment: Perhaps [this](https://www.madboa.com/geek/pine-ssl/) article can guide you to reverse engineer the answer yourself.